# Total Variation of Constant Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to prove that the total variation of, $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, is $0$ iff $f$ is a constant function, but i'm not entirely sure how. I can intuitively see why that it would be zero since the Total Variation of a function represents the number of peaks of the function. Though, how to rigorously prove it i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very definition of total variation of $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbf R$ is 
$$
\def\TV{\mathop{\rm TV}}\TV(f) = \sup \left\{
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)}\biggm| a \le x_1 < \cdots < x_n \le b, n \in \mathbf N\right\} $$
If $f$ is constant, for every choice of points $x_1 < \cdots < x_n$ each of the summands $\abs{f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)}$ is zero, hence, for a constant $f$, we are taking the supremum of the set $\{0\}$, so $\TV(f) = 0$ for constant $f$.

Comment: Ah okay. Notation question -- Is $TV(f)$ the same as $Var(f)_{[a,b]}$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on martini's answer, if $f$ is not constant, there exists two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. Thus,

$$TV(f) \geq |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| > 0$$